# How do you install a module in Lyx?

Tags: installing, lyx, modules

How do you install a module in Lyx?
I find this site is not helpful enough:
http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules

Comment: which module are you trying to install? exactly what error or problem do you get when trying to follow the instructions on that link?

Comment: I'm trying to install a longtables module.  I find LaTeX documents with longtables that compile well in Kile. But after being imported into Lyx they don't work properly.

Comment: When I follow the instructions on the link, Lyx appears completely unchanged.

Comment: I was trying to follow this website for the Longtable installation but there wasn't enough instruction there:
http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2010/07/13/custom-lyx-modules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the Lyx configuration directory (LCD), which will be `.lyx` on many installations.

Put your module in the `layouts` subdirectory of LCD.

Tell Lyx about your module by adding a line to the `lyxmodules.lst` file in the CFD, which has six strings.  I give an example in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9041/how-to-create-1-a-new-environment-for-lyxs-environment-drop-down-menu-2-a-n/9073#9073) to the *How to create (1) a new Environment for LyX's Environment drop-down menu, (2) a new Text Style* question.

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I honestly couldn't find that documented anywhere.

Comment: On some :-) installations, `layouts` will be `AppData\Local\Programs\LyX [version]\Resources\layouts`. But I believe this file can be created/updated from Lyx using the [document properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEYlh.png). See [Can I change options of packages loaded by a Lyx module?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318745/289991)

Answer (score 7):

You can find an overview into what goes into installing a module at:

http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2009/11/02/custom-lyx-nih

Here is the takehome, though:

1. Locate your LyX users directory. You can do this by clicking on Help -> About LyX. (If using a Mac, it is located under the Application menu.) It will usually be listed under the library directory in the About pane.
2. The user directory will have several folders. Look for one called "layouts" (as noted by the answer above). Copy your module folder into this folder.
3. Run the "Reconfigure" utility from the "Tools" menu. This will regenerate the `lyxmodules.lst` file. (In general it is not a good idea to edit this file by hand.)
4. Restart LyX. The new module will appear under "Modules" in the Document Settings window.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go, but my experience is that step 3 did not include the module I added to the `layouts` folder in the `lyxmodules.lst` file.