# Use algorithmic in LyX

Tags: lyx, algorithmic

I'm used to using the `algorithmic` package in LaTeX, but don't see an easy way to use it in LyX. I even tried [this](http://bgu.perso.libertysurf.fr/), but  it didn't work. Further, it required me to change my document type, which is a problem for me, as I am writing my thesis and require a specific document type.

How may I go about using the `algorithmic` package in LyX?

Technical specs:

- Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)
- LyX 2.0.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [LyX way of inserting algorithms](http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/I18n/lang-algorithm.lyx):

1. Insert->Float->Algorithm
2. Insert->TeX Code
3. Paste your `algorithmic` code from your favorite editor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Though it is an improvement, it seems so tedious. Is there no better way?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: See the updated answer.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, there is another way. It is possible to use the mentioned package but in a modified way - see my answer...

Answer (score 13):

The mentioned [Algorithm-Style Package for LyX](http://bgu.perso.libertysurf.fr/) (version 0.3) does not provide LyX module support since it was written for an older LyX version without module support. My approach **creates a LyX module** that can be **used with every document class**. Hence, it circumvents the necessity of the original package to use a certain document class.

The instructions below will install the package and add module support. Actually they replace the instructions of `Readme.txt` of the package. The files `algorithm.inc` and `article-algo.layout` of the original package are not needed anymore. `$HOME` will stand for your home directory.

1. unpack the archive `algo-0.3.tar.gz`,
2. copy the file `algorithm.inc` to `$HOME/.lyx/layouts` and rename it to `algolyx.module`,
3. insert the following lines at the very beginning of the file `algolyx.module`

   ```
   #\DeclareLyXModule{Algorithm support for LyX}
   #DescriptionBegin
   #This module provides a text style to write algorithms using the
   #packages "algorithm" and "algorithmic".
   #DescriptionEnd
   ```

   (Now `algolyx.module` became the needed module.)
4. in LyX run "Tools > Reconfigure" and restart LyX,
5. copy the file `algolyx.sty` to the directory `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex` (needs to be created possibly) and run `texhash` (or alternatively, copy the file `algolyx.sty` into each directory that contains a LyX document using this module).

For your document, add the module "Algorithm support for LyX" under "Document settings > Modules". In an algorithm float ("Insert > Float > Algorithm") choose the text style "Algorithm" and write an algorithm. The indentation is controlled by using nesting of lists, that is, "Increase depth" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and "Decrease depth" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>. Each statement starting without any keyword must be preceded by a star `*`. Here is an example:

[image]

For more examples, have a look at [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98918/24449) or the example provided by `algo-0.3.tar.gz` (to get it working with the modified setup, you need to add the module "Algorithm support for LyX" and change the document class to "article").

Comment: I mention in my question that I can't change the document type, as I am writing my thesis. I explained that as a result, the `algo` package, which I linked to in my question, doesn't work for me

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, I know that restriction and therefore I showed in my answer how to circumvent it... My answer shows how to create a LyX module for the package and how to set it up. (Not all files of the original package are needed anymore!) BTW, a LyX module can be added to a document *without* changing the document class.

Comment: Followed your instructions to the tee and even tried suggestions from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-to-install-an-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-mac/109916#109916). I was ultimately unable to find "Algorithm support for LyX" under "Document settings > Modules".

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It seems that the LyX module "Algorithm support for LyX" which was newly created in step 2 and 3 was not recognized. Did you put the file "algolyx.module" (which should look like [this](http://pastebin.com/GcCa1LEL)) into the directory `~/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.0/layout` instead of `~/.lyx/layout` since you are using Mac?

Comment: Yes. I tried putting the module in both locations, which still didn't work

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I guess you ran "reconfigure" and restarted LyX afterward as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9389. I'm out of ideas but the problem seems about installing a new LyX module.

Comment: After running `texhash` I had to Reconfigure and restart lyx again. 
Also on debian I had to put `algolyx.sty` under `/usr/local/share/texmf/` as root.

Now it works, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to add a keyword?

Comment: How do you use tabulation in this float window?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7,`algolyx.module` has to be put under `%APPDATA%\LyX2.0\layouts`, where the value of `%APPDATA%` can be checked by running "**set**" in command prompt.