# Adding keywords to an algorithm in LYX

Tags: lyx, algorithms, keywords

I am using the method explained [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115729/49617) to add algorithms in LYX.
I wonder if it is possible to add new keywords like (Input, Output, ...) so they appear in bold.
I use [Algorithm-Style Package for LyX](http://bgu.perso.libertysurf.fr/)

Comment: There is very few that isn't feasible in TeX.  You need to specify your question a bit.

Comment: Keywords are recognized and bolded, like "if", "for", ... I want to add some keywords like "Inputs:" so they look the same way.