# Multiple arguments for modules in LyX - Importing algorithms2e with multiple options in LyX

Tags: lyx, package-options, modules

I want to use the `algorithm2e` package in LyX (version 2.2.3). There is a LyX module that makes this task simple. However, I would like to adjust the arguments with which the package is imported.

The LaTeX code generated by LyX reads

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

What I want is something like

```
\usepackage[lined, algonl, boxed]{algorithm2e}
```

As pointed out in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280938/can-i-change-options-of-packages-loaded-by-a-lyx-module), the options with which a package imported by a module is loaded can be changed by going to `Document > Settings > Local Layout` and entering package options like

```
PackageOptions algorithm2e lined
```

This adds the line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{lined}{algorithm2e}
```

to the source code before the import of `algorithm2e`. Accordingly, I have tried to pass multiple arguments:

```
PackageOptions algorithm2e lined
PackageOptions algorithm2e algonl
PackageOptions algorithm2e boxed
```

However, only the last `PackageOptions` line is considered in the code, which reads

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{boxed}{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

This might be wanted behaviour (or not - I do not know whether `PassOptionsToPackage` can be applied multiple times). Nevertheless, the question remains: How can I add multiple package options?

I have tried to import `algorithm2e` in the "Latex-Preamble" in the document settings of LyX. However, this results in a conflict with the internal LyX solution. I get an error stating `Command \algorithm already defined`.

Would it be an option to write a new LyX module with adjusted import? How could I do this? The [LyX documentation on modules](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Manuals#Customization) is not detailed. I looked at the code of the `algorithm2e` module but did neither understand it completely nor find a line that I could adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the [`algorithm2e`](/ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) module from Document > Settings... > Modules and then add the following to your Local Layout:

```
Format 60
PackageOptions algorithm2e "lined, algonl, boxed"
```

This ensures that all 3 options are passed to `algorithm2e` when loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Werner's is the correct solution.

However, as an alternative, you could do the following.

Do not add the predefined module.

Go to `Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble` and add directly:

```
\usepackage[lined, algonl, boxed]{algorithm2e}
```

The drawback of this solution is that, afterwards, you have to insert your algorithm by ERT code directly:

[image]

because, not having loaded its module, LyX doesn't know you're using that package.

Comment: This does not work, because it interferes with the builtin algorithm environment in LyX. I described this in my post above.

Comment: Thanks, @CarLaTeX. It still does not work, though - even with "Provides algorithm 1".

Comment: @Samufi My original solution works, but you have to write your algorithm with ERT. Werner's answer is better.

Comment: I see... I guess, if I would have gone with ERT in the first place, the whole issue would not have come up. Thanks for researching, though @CarLaTeX!

Comment: @Samufi You're welcome! We're here to help. However,  Werner's answer is more convenient, because you don't need to use ERT. :)