# Typing expectation value in LyX

Tags: lyx

In quantum mechanics it is often needed to write the expectation value of an observable:

[image]

How do I type such in LyX?
I can write a bra using `\left\langle ___ \right|` and a ket with `\left| ___ \right\rangle` or simply with "Insert delimiters", but I have no idea how to insert a third, middle object between a bra and a ket.

Comment: Do you know how to load the `braket` package? If so, you could type `\braket{\psi|A|\psi}`.

Comment: No, I don't. Actually am not familiar with the "behind the scenes" stuff. But I guess you can guide me and I will make it through.

Comment: Do learn about ERTs ("Evil Red Tags"). They are lyx's way to allow users to enter LaTeX code directly into a document.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48031/lyx-quick-way-to-insert-dirac-bra-ket/48038#48038 helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to use

```
\left\langle \psi \middle| A \middle| \psi \right\rangle
```

To get an even more fancy view in LyX, you could wrap this in a math macro (Insert --> Math --> Macro)

Answer (score 1):

Include the physics package by typing:

```
\usepackage{physics}
```

Then you can use bra and ket commands:

```
$\bra{\psi}A\ket{\psi}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!