# Documentation on the arguments used when defining styles in an .inc file

Tags: lyx

I am new to using LyX, and recently asked a question about adding a modified style in an .inc file ([Add caution and warning messages to book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215417/add-caution-and-warning-messages-to-book)).  One of the problems I had was finding documentation on the components or arguments of the modified style, such as Category, Margin, & LabelString.  Is there a document or book where these are described?  And what "language" are they in:  LyX, LaTeX, or something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is in Help > Customization . I guess we would call the language "LyX's layout format language".